# Separate Google login from Google Calendar API

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-signin

I have a platform that allows people to sign up/log in with their Google account.
Inside the platform, there is a calendar feature where people can connect their Google Calendar and share the data between our app.

I'd like to know if there's a way to separate google calendar with the normal login stuff, so when they sign up with Google, we won't be asking for their Google Calendar permission. Once they are in the app, if they want to connect their Google Calendar, they can do so by clicking another button.

Currently, the 2 things are linked together and I'd like to separate them.
My app is https://clascity.com/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: please edit your question and include your signup code

Answer (score 1):

Just because you use Google signin (openid connect) does not mean that you have permission to access the users Google calendar data.

Google calendar data is private user data, you need specific permission to access the users calendar data, you cant just let them login without asking for permission to access the data you need to access.  The user needs to know what data you will be accessing and accept that specifically though the authorization form that google supplies.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering my question! I'm fully aware that I'll need to ask for permission to access their Google calendar data. What I'd like to do though is to not ask for that permission during the signup flow. instead, I'd have another button for connecting the google calendar after signing up. Is there something I can do on google console to separate them?

Comment: Edit your question and include your signup code, i would assume you should be able to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact, what you are suggesting is considered a best practice [1]. Use incremental authorization as described here [2].

[1] https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/policies#unbundled-consent

[2]
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth